# QProcess not starting

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, qprocess

I have following code:

```
proc = new QProcess();
proc->startDetached("C:\\ffmpeg.exe", QStringList() <<"-i"<< "C:\\pics\\frame%d.png"<< "-r"<< "30" << "-vcodec"<< "ffv1" << "C:\\test.avi" );
connect(proc,SIGNAL(finished(int)),this,SLOT(finishedFFMPEG(int)));
```

For some reason the SIGNAL for finished() and started() never gets called. The test.avi file is being created correctly.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

[`QProcess::startDetached`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached) is a static function. It has no effect on the instance of `QProcess`.

Use [`QProcess::start`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) instead.

Also the backslashes in `"C:\pics\frame%d.png"` should be escaped, or even better use slashes (`"C:/pics/frame%d.png"`) or a C++11 raw literal(`R"(C:\pics\frame%d.png)"`).

Comment: QProcess::start is not doing anything for some reason. QProcess::startDetached runs the process correctly but none of the signals for finished() and started() are being called

Comment: @testus Because `startDetached` has nothing to do with `proc`. It is a static function. The proper syntax should be: `QProcess::startDetached( ... ) `. It leaves your `proc` unaffected. Hence the signals will never be emitted.

Comment: Ok, I get that but how come `proc->start("C:\\ffmpeg.exe", QStringList() <<"-i"<< "C:\\pics\\frame%d.png"<< "-r"<< "30" << "-vcodec"<< "ffv1" << "C:\\depth.avi" );` is not doing anything?

Comment: Check it it emits the `started` signal.

Comment: It doesn't. I found out that if I create a QProcess object instead of QProcess* it will emit the signals. But I can't use QProcess in my case

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the right signature for the signal finished - it emits (int, QProcess::ExitStatus), not just int. You should check the result of connect(), always. And check the debug output as connect() will complain in the debug output if it couldn't make the connection you ask.

Comment: Or use the new Qt5 connect() syntax where you would get a compile error if you screw up the arguments.